# Additional route in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 5.2.2
```

In my routes.rb file, I have:

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :new, :create, :update] do
  put 'disable', on: :member
end
```

When I do rake routes, I get:

```
disable_user PUT    /users/:id/disable(.:format) users#disable
       users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
             POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
        user PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
```

Why do I have a duplicate of the update route? or this just a visual artifact of the rake route command?

Comment: `PATCH` and `PUT` are not identical. You can [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=PUT+vs+PATCH) to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails originally only used the PUT http verb for updates. In [2012 PATCH was declared the new primary HTTP method](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/2/26/edge-rails-patch-is-the-new-primary-http-method-for-updates/) for updates because of the semantics of how [IETF defines PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4).

> Now let’s say a web application has an Invoice model with a paid flag
> that indicates whether the invoice has been paid. How do you set that
> flag in a RESTful way? Submitting paid=1 via PUT to /invoices/:id does
> not conform to HTTP semantics, because such request would not be
> sending a complete representation of the invoice for replacement.

The entire discussion on the hows and why's can be found in [issue #348](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/348).

However for legacy compatibility reasons the `resources` and `resource` macros still generate a PUT route. This was a better compromise than breaking the Rails router to treat PUT and PATCH identically.

Why this legacy compatibility still is here in 2019 is another really good question.

Comment: If you want to get all semantical your route should be `patch 'disable', on: :member` for the same reasons.